# AWS ec2 instance created so many other resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-billing

I am new to AWS. I want to test my free tier. Today i created a free EC2.micro instance. Its working successfully, i didn't create anything else, but when i go to Resource Group -> Tag Editor and try to list all resources in all region, it is listing 168 resources

One is my EC2 instance (I created)
others are DHCPOptions, InternetGateway, NetworkAcl, Subnet, RouteTable, VPC, SecurityGroup, Volume, DBSecurityGroup      with different regions (I don't why they are here)

I want to know all this above are come under free tier or its going to make a huge $$$ bill???

How can i see my billing live?

Answer (score 4):

Some resources are created by AWS and are not charged.

One of the reasons you see so many resources is because AWS creates a **VPC** in **each region** for you. It also creates a default SG, Subnets, Routing Tables and so on.

They are not charged.

You can click on your organization name and then on **My Billing Dashboard** to see the current bill amount and a monthly estimate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VPC is like your private space. It is a network isolation from other customers and provide all the basics needed for network and therefore it contains things like subnets, Internet Gateway, routes, NACL, Subnet, Security group... and are all free (except things like data transfer between subnets in different datacenters, but it is not your case)

You also have an EBS created, which is the disk for your EC2. There is a free tier for that, so after one year you will pay it, like your EC2.